# Unable to target .NET Framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

For my project I'm required to target Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, but am unable to do so.

[image: Targets]

Installed programs:

[image: Programs]

Whenever I try to install .NET Framework 4.5, it tells me it's already installed:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the latest update to Visual Studio 2013 which is Update 4. If it is installed, then do another install but select `repair`. Restart if necessary and try again.

Comment: Thanks! I already have update 4,  but a VS2013 repair + restart fixed it. :)

Comment: @Nicholas The question got me thinking, was 4.5.1 a *full* replacement for 4.5 and that was why its not showing. But it is not, just a minor version upgrade; worth the effort to get it mind you. :-) Glad to help. I had a WP8 emulator die because I installed an Azure install and after a couple of hours tried the `repair`, which worked. So any Visual Studio bugs I see on SO, this is the answer more than not.